# how to enable scrolling rather than squashing divs together

Tags: html, css, scroll

on my website it is a div based layout when the window is reszied everything is pushed together. Such as images overlap or are moved below each other and divs also overlap each other.

How can I get it to scroll when the content of the div is greater than the window size, similar to facebook if you resize the window it prevents anything overlappting and just makes the user scroll?

```
body
{
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;        
}

#header
{   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#content
{

    width: 80%;
    height: 800px;  
    margin-top: 50px;       
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 30px;      
}

<div id="header">
[Header]
</div>
<div id="content">
[Content]
<img src="image1.png" /><img src="image2.png"/><img src="image3.png" />
</div>
```

The html is like that but obviously with more content

Hope I haven't made this too confusing, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Just add `overflow:auto;` to your div.

You can also use the following if you only want x or y scrolling

```
overflow-x:auto;
```

or

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `overflow:scroll;` to enable scrolling in the DIVs

Comment: Thanks but I want the whole page to scroll not just one div.

Comment: @Elliott - In that case try overflow:auto; or add overflow:scroll on the body class in css.

Answer (score 2):

You must add `white-space:nowrap;` to your body tag.

Comment: That works kind of, although I have to scroll when its full size and all my content is one line.

Comment: What happens if you forget about the white-space property and replace width:70%; by max-width:70%; in the #content element?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may want `overflow: auto;`

[Here's a comparison](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) between `auto` and `scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

add the style

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to `#content`

Comment: I just added this but it shows scroll bars before it is resized, and it doesn't scroll horizontally either. Thanks.

Comment: @Elliot, try `overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;` And what do you mean by "resized"?

Comment: Resize the browser window. I tried that and it hasn't made any difference , I want to enable scrolling before anything starts being overlapped. On facebook you can reszie the window only to a certain point, before scrolling starts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty late, however I stumbled across this question, as I was having issues on one of my pages, where I have this Page with 30 odd inputs of various types, that are split between two tables. I was unable to scroll to see about 10 or so inputs at the bottom of the page, and could not even scroll left to right when adjusting the browsers width.

What solved my issue was:

```
    html, body {
    overflow: visible;
    }
```

This activated my X and Y scroll bar.

I had an issue with my footer not adjusting when scrolling, it instead would just stay fixed where it was situated before scrolling. this was due to my master CSS having the footer's position set as absolute. Simple fix, just creating a new style element in the page and added

```
footer {
        position: fixed;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
```

I hope this helps anyone looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by user3726345 , the best option to use is the

```
html,body {
overflow: visible;
}
```

using

```
overflow: auto;
```

dosnt give the best output. then you can further adjust your footer codes to your taste.